# Automatically adjust window width in tmux

Tags: tmux

Is there a way to set tmux so that it automatically adjusts window width when I switch to the pane so that it will be wide axactly as the longest (visible on screen) line in the file I have open?

I'm doing this manually with the command
`:resize-pane -R 10`
or
`:resize-pane -L 10`
I always have to guess the number and when I switch to another pane I have to do it again

Note that this functionality is relevant only to vertical panes.

Answer (score 5):

There does not seem to be a way to do this automatically.  You can, however use the mouse:

```
 mouse-resize-pane [on | off] 
    If on, tmux captures the mouse and allows panes to be
    resized by dragging on their borders.
```